# Please fix my function ive tried everything but i cant get my while loop to end when the function is over

Tags: python-2.7

When i run this and type start it doesnt stop and return back to the console

```
#this code defines the menu:
def main():
      print('this will be the main menu') 
      return(Menu == False) 
#this was temporary code to prevent the menu from launching on start up this function will soon be used to start other functions from the 'console' onces i add a dictionary of functions
Menu = False
def Mcall(x):
     Menu = True
     while Menu == True:
         Menu = main()
#this code is a console or menu that should start functions or end the program
while(True):
      CP = raw_input("enter a comand:\n")
      if CP == 'start':
           Mcall('start')
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show properly formatted code? We cannot follow what you have.

Comment: what does your code actually do?. if you want to start a function when script is invoked, you can use `if __name__ == "main": startup() ` and create dict of function as you want

Comment: It is completely unclear what you're trying to do. If you don't want the code on the last 3 lines to run indefinitely, why is it in a `while True` block? Please [edit] your question to correct the indentation (`def main()` and `while(True)` should not be indented) and include a detailed description of what exactly you're trying to do, as well as how the current code isn't doing what you want. Additionally, you've tagged the question as `python-3.x` but you're using `raw_input` in your code, which is only in Python 2. Please take the time to review your posts before you submit them.

Comment: Im trying to get main() to end and return to the while(True):  loop after it is called.

Comment: @priyesh kumar would you mind explaing or linking to an explaination of how that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figgued it out! 
I was trying to end the while loop while inside a function with Menu = False when it needed to be under the function on the loop's indentation. Why it doesent work this way im not sure but I bet it has something to do with global variables not being changed within a function.